# Ponte Carlo, Ponte di Carlo

Tags: vocabulary

Please help me to translate the following sentence into Italian: I think that Charles Bridge is a great example of Gothic architecture.

My attempt: Penso che il Ponte Carlo sia un grande esempio di architettura gotica.

I am not sure about the translation of Charles Bridge into Italian. According my current hypothesis, it is Ponte Carlo. It would be Ponte di Carlo, if it would be built, finished and named during the life of Charles IV., but it was originally called Stone Bridge and it was renamed later to Charles Bridge. Hence Ponte Carlo. Is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Are you referring to Charles bridge in Prague?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for welcoming me. Yes, I am referring to the Charles Bridge in Prague.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you are referring to Charles bridge in Prague, “ponte Carlo” is undoubtedly the aptest translation into Italian.

Indeed, many bridges and other stuff in Italy have a name with a similar structure: ponte Sisto, ponte Garibaldi, piazza Vittorio, Castel Sant'Angelo, Monte Mario. The main contender would be an adjective coined from the name's root, as in “mole Antonelliana” (from the surname of its architect Alessandro Antonelli).

As regards this particular bridge, the choice “ponte Carlo” is confirmed by: [Italian Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponte_Carlo) (not necessarily reliable), an Italian edition of the “Rough Guide” of Prague, the book *Praga* by Claudio Canal (clup, Milano 1987) and, perhaps more reliable of all, scholar, translator and poet Angelo Maria Ripellino in his *Praga magica* (quoted [here](https://www.academia.edu/29004523/Josef_%C5%A0vejk_e_Josef_K_sul_Ponte_Carlo_alcune_riflessioni_su_Praga_magica_)).

Comment: Great answer, this definitely seems to be the main structure. Further exceptions include _Ponte di Calatrava_ in Venice (despite its official name being _Ponte Costituzione_) and [_Ponte di Annibale_](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponte_di_Annibale)

Comment: I agree that the bridge is usually called “ponte Carlo”; however the Czech name is “Karlův most“ where Karlův is a possessive adjective. By the way, notwithstanding I've never touched the base of the statue representing St. John of Nepomuk, I've been there not less than 20 times. :-)